# Save Ping Output in a text file

Tags: windows-xp, ping

I often have to ping servers for connectivity status. Is there a way to save the **ping results (output) in a text file** so that I can save entire day's ping results in a text file.

I am using Windows XP SP3.

Ping example:

```
ping 192.168.1.1 -t 

(using windows' ping)
```

or

```
ping 192.168.1.1

(using cygwin)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use redirection, for example:

```
ping 192.168.1.1 -t > filename.txt
```

This will redirect all (standard) output from the program into `filename.txt`, which will be created if it doesn't exist and overwritten if it does.

You can use `>>` instead of `>` to redirect the output to a file and *append* the results to the end of the file, instead of overwriting *(with thanks to [@Jane T](https://superuser.com/users/49889/jane-t) for the reminder)*.

Note that you will *not* receive the normal on-screen output if you do this.

### Update in response to comment

To delay between pings and record the time of each, you can do some scripting.

Here is a quick Windows batch file I've thrown together. It prints the time, pings Google, then waits for 3 seconds before repeating itself. I'm *not* a batch file expert so if anyone spots any problems please flag them up! And this probably isn't the "best" way to achieve what you are after - that might make for a separate question really.

```
@ECHO OFF

:LOOPSTART

time /T
ping www.google.com -n 4
sleep -m 3000

GOTO LOOPSTART
```

Save this in a `.bat` file somewhere, edit the ping target and delay time as you need it, then run the `.bat` using redirection to pump the output of the whole thing to a file. You may need to replace the `sleep -m 3000` command with `timeout /T 3` depending on your Windows version.

Note that this batch file **never ends**, but can be terminated by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and then <kbd>Y</kbd> if run from `cmd`. (You **must** press Y because it asks if you want to stop the batch file - even though you cannot see the question because you've redirected the output!)

Comment: thanks! works well, can I show current time along with every ping, or can I change the duration between two pings

Comment: You'd have to do some scripting for this, ping won't be able to do it for you.

Comment: Azz beat me to it - for that you'd need to change `ping` itself to output something different, or do some interesting scripting effort to - for example - output a timestamp, ping, wait 10seconds, repeat.

Comment: glad to hear it can be done. waiting for more. has windows scripting got to do anything with this

Comment: "so that I can save entire day's ping results in a text file"   You will need to use >> to append data to the output file.

Comment: Thank you @Jane, for some reason I always mental blank on redirect+append.

Comment: The sleep command is not identified under windows 7 PC

Comment: Note that once you do CTRL+C ping will end but you will not see standard ping summary (lost packages and such). So you might need to use `ping -n` rather then `ping -t`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the command prompt just redirect it to a text file using this format

```
ping 192.168.1.1 > ping.txt
```

That will do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
> ping 192.168.1.1 -t > ping-results
```

Comment: Using **`>`** as your `PS1` shell prompt is really confusing when the command also includes a `>` for redirection.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the script that pings google.com every 5 seconds and logging results with current time. Here you can find output to variables "commandLineStr" (with indices)

```
@echo off

:LOOPSTART

echo %DATE:~0% %TIME:~0,8% >> Pingtest.log

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET scriptCount=1
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`ping google.com -n 1`) DO (
  SET commandLineStr!scriptCount!=%%F
  SET /a scriptCount=!scriptCount!+1
)
@ECHO %commandLineStr1% >> PingTest.log
@ECHO %commandLineStr2% >> PingTest.log
ENDLOCAL

timeout 5 > nul

GOTO LOOPSTART
```

Answer (score 1):

::PIng ISP Every 1 Seconds and write date , time and result to Text File

```
@ECHO OFF
:LOOPSTART
date /T >>Pingtest.log
time /T >>Pingtest.log
ping 8.8.8.8 -n 1 >>PingTest.log
sleep -m 1000
GOTO LOOPSTART
```

Answer (score 1):

Also if you want to see the ping results in display you can use this code

```
@ECHO OFF
:LOOPSTART
date /T >>Pingtest.log
time /T >>Pingtest.log
REM this line show you the ping results in display
ping 8.8.8.8 -n 1 

REM this line print the ping results in the log file
ping 8.8.8.8 -n 10 >>PingTest.log
sleep -m 1000
GOTO LOOPSTART
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash

ping -i 0.5  google.com | while read pingresponse; do echo "$(date): $pingresponse"; done > pingStream.txt
```

Comment: (1) @AndrewMorton: I’m not sure that your comment is entirely valid, since the question indicates that Cygwin is available.  But (2) saxjax: What’s with the ``-i``?  My Windows `ping` says “Bad value for option -i, valid range is from 1 to 255.” and my Cygwin `ping` doesn’t recognize `-i` at all.  Also, (3) we don’t like code-only answers.  It is better to explain what your code is doing and how it is doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple....

Create one file called ip.txt and type the IPs and create the .bat file below.

```
@Echo Off

Set "ServerList=C:\Users\Script Ping-NSLook\ip.txt"
Set "LogFile=C:\Users\Script Ping-NSLook\PingResults.txt"

If Not Exist "%ServerList%" Exit /B
>"%LogFile%" (For /F UseBackQ %%A In ("%ServerList%"
) Do Ping -n 1 %%A|Find "TTL=">Nul&&(Echo Yes [%%A])||Echo No [%%A])
```

Enjoy:)

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! How is your answer better than the accepted one? If you write a so similar answer, please explain in which aspect yours is better.