# Batch file to write ping results to a text file

Tags: windows-7, batch, ping, batch-file

I know this is a variation of an already asked question but after research and several failed attempts I think I need some help.

I would like to ping two websites repeatedly and record the time and results in a text file.

I found this question [Save Ping Output in a text file](https://superuser.com/questions/196920/save-ping-output-in-a-text-file) to be very helpful but the several versions I have tried do not work.

If I execute the following in a command window, it creates the text file in my users directory as I would expect with the repeated pings recorded correctly.

```
ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -t > filename.txt
```

But if I create the following ping.dat file and save it on my desktop. When I run it, it both opens a cmd window with the just time in it and also creates the desired textfile on my desktop. Unfortunately the file only contains the time and not the ping results and the results are obviously not 3seconds apart like expected.

```
@ECHO OFF
:LOOPSTART
time /T
ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -n 4 >> filename.txt
ping yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy -n 4 >> filename.txt
sleep -m 3000
GOTO LOOPSTART
```

I assumed that my problem was related to how I was trying to write the results but if I modify the batch file, deleting the '>> filename.txt' reference all it does is open a cmd window which instantly fills up with time stamps.

```
@ECHO OFF
:LOOPSTART
time /T
ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -n 4
ping yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy -n 4
sleep -m 3000
GOTO LOOPSTART
```

Hence my questions are

A) Any idea what I am doing wrong?

B) How do I change the time stamp so that it is HH:MM:SS rather than HH:MM

All help appreciated.

S.

@LInker3000 Thanks for the reply. I should have mentioned this in my original question, but I have already tried that. When I added '>> filename.txt' to the timestamp, I now get a command window that fills up with "The process cannot acces the file because it is being used by another process.". Upon terminating the process, the created txt file only has one timestamp and the "Terminate Batch Job (Y/N)" text.

Comment: Linker3000's solution works just how you want, over here.  I suspect that it is some anti-virus or syncing software which is locking the text file.  Try turning it off and try it again.

Comment: It seems that my problem was naming the file ping.bat as soon as I changed that to pingbatch.bat it started working. The Sleep function isn't working though. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: I did not noticed it not working earlier, but maybe it wasn't.  You could try `timeout` instead.

Comment: 'timeout /T 5 /nobreak' worked great Thank you.

Comment: There's also a crafty way to use PING for a delay (provided your computer is connected to a network): PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 >NUL   You just need to use an invalid address. Works great on older OSs that dont't have 'sleep'. Delay is in mS (3000 in the example)

Comment: Thanks Linker. Since everybody here seems to be so good at this let me ask one more question. Is there a way NOT to write the summary statistics to the text file. Ideally all I want is the 'Pinging xxx etc, Reply from...' or 'Pinging xxx etc, Request time out'

Comment: You could try `ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -n 4 | findstr Reply` to get only the ping results.

Comment: I'm working on copying the ping results to a temporary file and then copying the first 2 lines (pinging & reply or request timed out) of that temp file into my main file. Just trying to learn how to use FOR /F to load the first two lines of the temp file.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/309473/batch-file-that-copies-the-first-2-lines-of-a-text-file-into-another-text-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the timestamp in the file too, you'd need to put:

```
time /T >> filename.txt
```

In the first example you quoted:

```
@ECHO OFF
:LOOPSTART
time /T >> filename.txt
ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -n 4 >> filename.txt
ping yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy -n 4 >> filename.txt
sleep -m 3000
GOTO LOOPSTART
```

You can play around with the following code to give you a more configurable timestamp:

```
set time_hh=%time:~0,2%
if %time_hh% lss 10 (set time_hh=0%time:~1,1%)
set time_mn=%time:~3,2%
set time_ss=%time:~6,2%
set time_ms=%time:~9,2%

echo %time_hh%:%time_mn%:%time_ss%.%time_ms% >> filename.txt
```

Put all of this in place of the *time /t...* line

Answer (score 2):

To get the seconds (and milliseconds) replace `time /T` with `echo %time%` so you have:

```
@ECHO OFF
:LOOPSTART
echo %time% >> filename.txt
ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -n 4 >> filename.txt
ping yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy -n 4 >> filename.txt
sleep -m 3000
GOTO LOOPSTART
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out my template. It will ask you for the host ip. Just save it as `.bat` and run it. Enter the host IP when prompted.

```
@echo off

set/p host=host Address: 
set logfile=Log_%host%.log

echo Target Host = %host% >%logfile%
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('ping %host% -n 1 ') do (echo %%A>>%logfile% && GOTO Ping)
:Ping
for /f "tokens=* skip=2" %%A in ('ping %host% -n 1 ') do (
    echo %date% %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2% %%A>>%logfile%
    echo %date% %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2% %%A
    timeout 1 >NUL 
    GOTO Ping)
```

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP wants to ping two different hosts.

Comment: I just happened to stumble upon this and for me it's what I'm looking for... or it seems to be.
Thing is; The script doesn't seem to do anything? It creates a log file and sets the host address in it, and then..... nothing?

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF

:SERVER1    

for /F "tokens=* skip=2" %%A in ('ping -n 1 0.0.0.1 ') do (
   echo %date% %time% %%A >>filename.txt
   goto SERVER2 
)

:SERVER2

for /F "tokens=* skip=2" %%A in ('ping -n 1 0.0.0.1 ') do (
   echo %date% %time% %%A >>filename.txt
   goto SERVER1
)

EXIT
```